# How do I solve this equation when x approaches zero?

Tags: limits

I have tried to solve this limit problem but haven´t been able to come up with a solution. Any suggestion? I have tried to divide by the denominator, tried to rewrite the trigonometric expression but the problem that always frustrate me is the single x^4 in the denominator.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2\cos(x) - 2 + x^{2}}{x^{4}}$$

Comment: Do you know Taylor series or L"Hospital's Rule? Both would work here...

Answer (score 0):

Using Taylor series:

$$\frac{2\cos x-2+x^2}{x^4}=\frac{\left(2-x^2+\frac{x^4}{12}+\mathcal O\left(x^6\right)\right)-2+x^2}{x^4}=\frac{x^4}{12x^4}+\mathcal O\left(x^6\right)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac1{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Timbuc showed how the problem of the limit can easily be solved using Taylor series. In fact, this method allows to solve most (not to say all) problems of limits.

However, the same method can be used to do more and, in particular, to show how the limit is approached (this may not be of interest to you now but it will be soon). Just let us do the same as Timbuc but using one more term. We then have $$A=\frac{2\cos x-2+x^2}{x^4}=\frac{\left(2-x^2+\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{x^6}{360}+\mathcal O\left(x^8\right)\right)-2+x^2}{x^4}=\frac{\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{x^6}{360}+O\left(x^8\right)}{x^4}$$ So $$A=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{x^2}{360}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and the limit is approached from below.

I suggest you plot on the same graph the two functions $$f(x)=\frac{2\cos x-2+x^2}{x^4}$$ $$g(x)=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{x^2}{360}$$ for $-2 \leq x \leq +2$; you should be amazed to see how close they are.

This means that if you had to solve the equation $$\frac{2\cos x-2+x^2}{x^4}=0.08$$ which does not show any analytical solution, you can solve the quadratic (given by $g(x)$) and get an estimate $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}\approx 1.09545$ while the "exact" solution is $\approx 1.10747$.

If tou had added the next term of the series, the approximating function would heve been $$g(x)=\frac{1}{12}-\frac{x^2}{360}+\frac{x^4}{20160}$$ and solving again the quadratic (given by $g(x)$) would give  $x_0=2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{5} \left(35-4 \sqrt{70}\right)}\approx 1.10765$ which is very close to the solution.